# Is there a way to automatically add "using static MyExtensions;" to all new LINQPad queries?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I've declared the following static member in LINQPad's `MyExtensions` class:

`public static Random rng = new Random();`

This works fine - in any new query, I can access it via, e.g. `MyExtensions.rng.Next()`. I can also paste `using static MyExtensions;` at the top of each new file so that I can save a bit of typing and do `rng.Next()`.

Is there a way to make `using static MyExtensions;` the default for all new queries? I've tried adding the line to `MyExtensions`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Press **F4** to bring up the **Query Properties**.

Switch to **Additional Namespace Imports.**

Add **static MyExtensions**

Click on S**et as default for new queries**.